# HTTPD Redirect Doesn't Work with Environment Variables

Tags: redirects, apache, httpd

We want to redirect users from an old domain to a new domain defined in an environment variable:

```
SetEnvIfExpr true SERVER_HOST_NAME=mynewdomain.example
```

The follwoing works in Apache 2.4 to redirect to a defined host name in an environment variable:

```
Redirect permanent https://%{env:SERVER_HOST_NAME}/
```

This however does not:

```
Redirect permanent / https://%{env:SERVER_HOST_NAME}/
```

The 2nd option is preferable because it maintains the path so if the request is:

```
GET https://myOLDdomain.example/somepath
```

The first option will always redirect the user to:

```
    GET https://mynewdomain.example/
```

instead of:

```
    GET https://mynewdomain.example/somepath
```

Currently the 2nd option redirects the user (literally) to:

```
    GET https://%{env:SERVER_HOST_NAME}/somepath
```

Is it a bug that Apache is not resolving `%{env:SERVER_HOST_NAME}`?

Comment: Why not just use `Redirect permanent / https://mynewdomain.example/`?  There is no need to put it in a variable.

Comment: We have our reasons: the same apache httpd.conf can be used in different docker containers with different configuration (via environment variables).

Comment: Did you try with `RedirectPermanent` instead? And which version of Apache?

Answer (score 1):

The use of an [expression](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/expr.html), like your `%{env:SERVER_HOST_NAME}`, at the URL of a `<Redirect>` is not possible, unless it's placed within a `<LocationMatch>` for example.

> ...
>   If the Redirect directive is used within a  or  section with the URL-path omitted, then the URL parameter will be interpreted using expression syntax.
>   This syntax is available in Apache 2.4.19 and later.
>   ...

See also https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

An example of this could look like this:

```
SetEnvIfExpr true SERVER_HOST_NAME=mynewdomain.example
<LocationMatch "^/(?<REMAINING>.*)">
    Redirect permanent https://%{env:SERVER_HOST_NAME}/%{env:MATCH_REMAINING}
</LocationMatch>
```

The named group, `REMAINING` at the [`<LocationMatch>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#locationmatch) allows you to append the requested URL path to the URL send with the redirect response. So the client gets redirect to the same URL path but on `SERVER_HOST_NAME`.